Having trouble proving an inequality
I was confused about a step when looking at a simple transformation of an inequality in a book Elliptic Partial Differential Equations by Qing Han and FangHua Lin. The picture below is the complete proposition and the proof process.

What I want to ask is that the $k$ selected in the last step may not exist, because $\rho$ here is arbitrary within the given range, and $\tau$ is fixed. Maybe $A$ will be large enough to make the fixed $\tau$ very small, so that:$$\tau^2<\rho/r\quad\text{implies}\quad 2\le k+1\le \frac{\log(\rho/r)}{\log\tau}<2.$$But if I don’t choose that $k$, I can’t prove the last inequality. How to solve this problem？Can someone help me, thanks.

what do you mean $\rho$ is fixed ? First, you choose $\rho$ and $r$, and then you are choosing $\tau.$

@dezdichado nonono, I mean $\tau$ is fixed, $\rho$ is a variable.

You are proving this for $\rho\leq r,$ so if you think of the interval $[0,r]$ as infinite union :
$$(\tau^{n+1}r, \tau^n r]$$, then $\rho$ must fall in one of them. Question is though that $k=-1$ or $k=0$ is possible but the proof is assuming $k>0.$
